# Laravel - Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I have a model for users

```
class User
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function blocks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Block::class, 'block_user', 'blocker_id', 'blocked_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And a model for blocks

```
class Block extends Model
{
    protected $table = "block_user";
}
```

So I have two tables: one for user information and the other for when one blocks another(Pivot Table) so `user_id` in users table is both local and foreign.

The problem is that when I want to get if user has blocked another user it returns an error saying: `Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'block_user'`

```
$user = User::where('user_id', 1)->first();
dd($user->blocks->first_name);
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Many to many relationships require a pivot, or intermediate, table.

Comment: As I said I have pivot table however I have only two tables. One of them users one of them pivot. Is there any need for another table?

Comment: But really I don't need one more! What this 3rd table should contain?! A user from `users` table blocks another user from `users` table and a pivot table that contains which user blocked which user in `block_user` table so I don't need another table. Do I?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.   You don't need a Block model.  The related model in this relationship is User.   It's `User -> blocks <- User`.   Because this is a many to many relationship, you'll never be able to do `$user->blocks->first_name` though.  `blocks` will be a collection.

Comment: But I didn't get what you mean! What should I do now? Should I change `Block::class` to `User::class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relating the User model to the User model, not to the Block model.  A model for a pivot table is not necessary and usually would never be used.

```
public function blocks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'block_user', 'blocker_id', 'blocked_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

So instead of relating to `Block::class` in your belongsToMany, relate to `User::class`.

Comment: I just did it but `$user->blocks()` doesn't return any value for blocked users.

Comment: `blocks()` is used to query the relationship, use the property `blocks` to get a collection.

Comment: Bingo :)) THANKS A LOT :)